# EF DbContext lifetime for quickly changing state

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, desktop-application

I have a desktop application that is using Entity Framework bound to SQL Server Compact for persistence.  The application stores various 'traditional' records (accessed periodically, but not modified very often), but it also is used for persisting highly mutable state used to restore application state between sessions.

Most of the recommendations I've read for Entity Framework involve keeping the DbContext lifetime relatively short (perhaps even method scope?), so as to avoid excessive memory usage over time.  For the highly mutable state, though, it seems like having a longer lifetime makes sense; the mutable state persists for the entire lifetime of the app however, which would mean keeping a context alive for the whole app lifetime.

I've considered keeping a separate DbContext instance for just the mutable state, then use method-scoped contexts for other operations, but this runs into problems due to the mutable state having (read-only) references to the less frequently modified records; this causes errors when I try to modify them from another DbContext.  I'm looking for suggestions from developers with more experience using EF as to the proper way to structure this.

Here is my current thought:

1. Use a single DbContext with app lifetime for all mutable state and any records they reference.
2. Use separate DbContext instances only for independent records, like data change history records and archived objects.

This still leaves a huge chunk of the database resident in memory all the time, but I'm not sure what else would work here.  Database size isn't too large (on order of only thousands of records), so this might be okay.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think your design will work well.  Also you may want to consider the "Repository" pattern.  It's a mediator between the DB and the Application just for EF.  You can put refresh rules there, such as "only update content to db once every 5 minutes" or "don't query DB if we already have this collection in memory and it was last refreshed 10 minutes ago.  etc. etc.

Comment: Lifetime sounds OK (although I don't like the idea on general principles). However, be very careful if you do any multithreaded stuff: DBContexts don't like it.

Comment: If you're thinking of keeping a DbContext alive for a long time for performance reasonse, I suggest that EF is not the correct choice to solve the problem. If the application state is local to the user or workstation (sounds like it might be), then perhaps SQL Server isn't the best choice either.

Comment: @Keith, the motivation is not primarily performance (though that's important), but rather the complications that ensue with navigation properties, since I want to keep the state objects around.  My motivation for using a database over some other proprietary storage is the desire to maintain referential integrity in the event of things like crashes or sudden power failures.

Comment: @simon, I just realized, this probably applies to navigation properties as well, even if I attempt to lock upon access to the 'global' context.  This does create some issues...

Comment: What I have done is convert the Linq query to a List<T> before closing the context. This forces a read of the query. Then when I need to update I create a new context and fetch the entities I need to update (I have the PK in the detached object) and update the new instance. I don't however change Nav properties too much.